# Include h1/h2/h3 and positioning then in html file using .css file

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```html
<div class="front-page">
<div id="header" class="mainclass">

<h1 class="secondclass">Main Title</h1>

</div>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to add h2 / h3 / h4 inside div: `<div id = "header" class = "mainclass">`?

There's more, how do I position them my way? That is, h2 will be on the right but just below h1,  h3 will be on the bottom right and h4 will be on the top right.

Is it possible to do that?

Any help guys?

Comment: Why not try? You can use float, flexbox and absolute positioning

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Is anything preventing you from adding `h2`, `h3` or `h4` element(s) inside the `<div id="header" ...` element? When you have added them, you can position them with CSS. What is your question and why don't you put the elements in your `div` in the first place, before asking how to position them?

Comment: my question was how to include h1 / h2 / h3 from a .css file.

Comment: What do you mean with "include ... from a .css file"? CSS files only contain rules, you can't include any HTML elements from CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this

```css
H1 {
  float: left
}

H2 {
  float: right
}

H3 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}

H4 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page">
  <div id="header" class="mainclass">

    <h1 class="secondclass">Main Title</h1>
    <h2 class="secondclass">H2</h2>
    <h3 class="secondclass">H3</h3>
    <h4 class="secondclass">H4</h4>

  </div>
</div>
```